# titanium alloy widget assets folder path

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-widgets

I have a problem referencing the assets (image) folder path for my widget on an `ImageView`.

I have the header widget and I want to add the home button image. the `home.png` is stored into `/widgets/widget.folder/assets/home.png`

The [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Widgets) says that I should use the `WPATH('home.png')` macro. I `Ti.API.info(WPATH('home.png'))` it and it excludes the assets folder, saying `/widget.folder/home.png` and the `$.lbutton.image = WPATH('home.png');` command doesn't show the image I want. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved changing the `ImageView` into a `Label` and assinging `Label.backgroundImage` to `'/image.png'` stored into the `assets` folder of the project. but don't know why `ImageView.image` doesn't display the image with the same path.

Comment: Saved a day. ImageView must be broken.

Comment: Helped me as well when resolving assets on Android (a local html file in my case).
Lifesaver!